# Games using google earth 3D data?

Tags: game, google-maps

Google earth (and maps on the desktop) contains a lot of 3D landscape and building data. While not exactly looking like professionally sculpted recreations of the cities, using the desktop client of google earth to take a stroll through the streets of Valetta was a nice experience.

[image: Looks nice enough if you don't look closely.]

This got me thinking: Are there any games already utilizing this data? I was thinking along the lines of jump&runs and flight simulators.

I could find several games making use of Google Maps satellite images or Streetview data, but I couldn't find anything making use of the 3D features.

A related [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379691/how-to-show-map-with-3d-buildings-with-google-maps-js-api/48073721#48073721) mentioned it wasn't supported by the JavaScript API about 2 years ago, but I failed to clarify if this is still true and whether the data is available through other endpoints.